# move directory contents to parent

Tags: shell-script, ls, mv

Have folder named debug and would like to move contents to parent directory

Tried:

```
ls -a debug/ | mv * .
```

Result (error):

```
mv: 'debug' and './debug' are the same file
```

It is trying to move the debug directory itself, right? How to prevent that?

Comment: Try: `mv debug/* .`

Comment: Powershell is almost completely different to shell scripting.

Answer (score 4):

You're overthinking. Don't use `ls` in this case. Just `mv` - `mv debug/* .` You can't pipe anything to `mv` the way you're trying to anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand several things about `.`, `..` and how to use them. Now from the answer given by John

```
mv debug/* .
```

this is saying move the content (all) of debug folder into my current folder, here represented by `.`. But a situation where you are in the debug folder then you will achieve the same with the following command:

```
mv * ../
```

This says: move everything to my current location (debug folder) to the **parent** folder here represented by `..`. So `.` stands for current folder, and `..` stands for parent folder with respect to where you currently are.